# Sync process new image manipulations in child folders (for use with P&T Assets)

Tags: assets, ce-image

I'm finding CE Image is incredibly slow even with CE Cache and native caching, and so I'm keen to move over to use native image manipulations.

However, because I use P&T Assets, my clients have added images in sub-folders to keep things organised. That means, when I add new native image manipulations and perform a sync, the sub-folders are effectively ignored.

Does anyone know how I can add new image manipulations, and have sub-folders processed?

Comment: If the content is cached (using native caching or CE Cache), then CE Image would only run the first time the page was loaded; subsequent requests would return the cached content and the plugin wouldn't even be called. Perhaps there is an underlying server issue?

Comment: I should say that the main problem is that there's a lot of content being added to the site all the time, and so the cache is getting constantly cleared. Allowing the cache to expire after the time limit isn't acceptable for the client: they want to see the newly published content right away.